# C: Learning to Code in C with pointers, Header files etc

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, header-files, extern

I am trying to create a simple C program while learning about the concepts about pointers, linked list and header files.
I want to create a simple C program by clubbing all these concepts together for better understanding.
My code and its explanation is as follows:

I have a header file "header1.h " where I have declared the structure which is to be shared between various source files and also the "head" variable of the linked list.
The header file is as follows:

header1.h

```
 struct node{

        char * name;
        struct node* next;
 };

 extern struct node* head;
```

Now, I have the main source-file named "start_prog.c" which has got the "main" function
and the menu which will control the execution of the of the program. 
Menu has various options such as Add element ,Delete element , Reverse List etc (for simplicity I will only present two options here viz, Insert and Print list which are most important).

from the start_prog.c I call the "create" function which will add the element to the list.
If the list does not exist then it will create one else It will append the element to the list after the last element.
The create function is defined in another source file "create.c".

Both the files are as follows:

start_prog.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "header1.h"    //include the header file

struct node* head = NULL;   //Define the external variable head to be null initially

struct node* create();
void main(void){


    int option;

    do{

       printf("\nplease select the option : \n\t\t1)add element \n\t\t2)Print List\n");

    scanf("\n%d",&option);

    switch(option){
    case 1:
            head = create();
            break;
    case 2:
            print_list();
            break;

    }

    }while(option != 3);

}
```

and the create.c file is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>                                                                                                              
#include "header1.h"
 //this function creates the linked list if the list is null or inserts the
 //element at the end of the list.


struct node* create() {

    if(head == NULL){

  //create a new list and return head.
      printf("\nhead is null\n");
      struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      char * new_name;
      printf("\nplease enter the new name\n  ");
      scanf("%s\n", new_name);
      newnode -> name = new_name;
      newnode -> next = NULL;
      head = newnode;
      return head; 



    }

    else if(head != NULL){

      printf("\nhead is not null\n ");
      struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      char * new_name;
      printf("\n Please Enter the new name \n");
      scanf("%s\n", new_name);
      newnode -> name = new_name;
      newnode -> next = NULL;

      struct node* ptr = NULL;

      ptr = head;
      while((ptr -> next) != NULL){

            ptr = ptr -> next;


      } 

            ptr -> next = newnode;
            return head;

    }



}
```

when I run all these programs together I get Garbage values in the head and Segmentation fault error. What is Wrong in my code. What is the thing that I am missing. I feel that I am close to understand the concepts but missing some important point due to which I am not 
able to write the program properly. Please find the bug/error in my code and the fault in my understanding.
Thankyou!

Comment: This is not a great question for SO i think ... maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be better, since you want someone to look and review your code? I'm sure that eventually someone will be happy to look at your code and try to help, but to help them help you, try to be more concise ...

Comment: I would ignore it there just as I'm ignoring it here for the same reason. If you can't be bothered to properly indent your code to make it readable, why should I take my time to read it?

Comment: It would be good time To learn to run the program under debugger. That's the first thing to do with segfaults, often (not always) the line where it happens will immediately reveal what pointer had invalid value.

Comment: Also, turn up compiler warnings. They would immediately tell you for example, that you give uninitialized pointer to `scanf` (which will segfault unless you're unlucky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Segmentation fault occurs when you to try to access or assign value from/to memory which is not assigned to that process.

Normally check places where you are assigning values or retrieving it whether your the is assigned to it or not.

one think i saw was

```
char * new_name; // declaring the pointer
printf("\n Please Enter the new name \n");
scanf("%s\n", new_name);//reading the value from stdin to where pointer is pointing
```

when you declare the pointer its filled with garbage value. which may be out of range of your process assigned memory. and your asking your compiler to store the value there which is illegal hence the kernel raises a signal SIGSEGV and halts your process.

Assign memory before assigning the value

> new_name = malloc(20); // how much ever you think is required

Answer (score 1):

In your create.c file

`char * new_name;
printf("\nplease enter the new name\n  ");
scanf("%s\n", new_name);`

How will that above code execute, Please try to use array to store name temporarily there.
if you want to use pointer there then you have to allocate memrory for that poiner too.
and dont use `'\n'` in the scanf like that or else, it will not stop even when you press enter key it will stop only when you press any non-white space charater,which would be awfull.

Comment: thankyou for the '\n' suggestion. Can you explain why it happens ?

Comment: To understand that you should know what are whiteSpace characters. '\n' '\t' '\v' '\f' '\r' and ' '(space) are whiteSpace characters.In your example after reading the string when you hit enter key, a `'\n'` is generated from your side which is compared with `'\n'` present in the scanf() as both are whitespace characters your `'\n'` is discarded(ignored),In order stop that input proces, you have to press any  **Non whiteSpace character** (other key except Enter or space bar or tab key).if hit 'z'key then 'z' will be generated and compared with '\n' as they are not same the scanf() will stop.

Comment: I know this might sound confusing but try learn it. If you want to discard `'\n'` character there are many ways to do it. You could us `while(getchar()!='\n');` this will remove any remaining unread character from input buffer.